# Error code 30000 sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_CAR (
 CARID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
 DATE_NEW TIMESTAMP,
 DATE_EDIT TIMESTAMP,
 USER_NEW VARCHAR(63),
 USER_EDIT VARCHAR(63),
 MANUFACT VARCHAR(50),
 MODEL VARCHAR(50),
 MILEAGE INTEGER,
 PURCHDATE TIMESTAMP,
 BATCH VARCHAR(50),
 FUELTYPE INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (CARDID));
```

and it still returns

> Error code 30000, SQL state 42X93: Table 'TEST_CAR' contains a
>   constraint definition with column 'CARDID' which is not in the table.
>   Line 1, column 1

---

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_LIST (
 LISTID CHAR (36) NOT NULL,
 CAR_ID  CHAR (36) NOT NULL,
 DRIVER_ID CHAR (36) NOT NULL,
 DATE_EDIT TIMESTAMP,
 DATE_NEW TIMESTAMP,
 USER_EDIT VARCHAR (63),
 USER_NEW VARCHAR (63),
 F_FROM VARCHAR (50),
 T_TO VARCHAR (50),
 KM INTEGER,
 DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (50),
 DATE_FROM TIMESTAMP,
 DATE_TO TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE INDEX ON TEST_LIST (CAR_ID ASC);
```

> Error code 30000, SQL state 42X93: Table 'TEST_LIST' contains a
>   constraint definition with column 'ID' which is not in the table. Line
>   1, column 1 Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error:
>   Encountered "ON" at line 1, column 14. Line 17, column 1

Comment: CARID <> CARDID...

Comment: CAR**D**ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,

Comment: `CARDID` should be `CARID ` because your column name is `CARID `

Comment: CARDID is CARID

Comment: yes sure but is car not card :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `CARDID` as primary key, whilst you named your column `CARID`.

Change

```
PRIMARY KEY (CARDID));
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY (CARID));
```

**Solution to your second problem**

You define `ID` as primary key even though `ID` is not in your table

Comment: and this ? CREATE TABLE TEST_LIST (
 LISTID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
 CAR_ID  CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
 DRIVER_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
 DATE_EDIT TIMESTAMP,
 DATE_NEW TIMESTAMP,
 USER_EDIT VARCHAR(63),
 USER_NEW VARCHAR(63),
 F_FROM VARCHAR(50),
 T_TO VARCHAR(50),
 KM INTEGER,
 DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
 DATE_FROM TIMESTAMP,
 DATE_TO TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE INDEX ON TEST_LIST (CAR_ID ASC); ??

Comment: Error code 30000, SQL state 42X93: Table 'TEST_LIST' contains a constraint definition with column 'ID' which is not in the table.
Line 1, column 1

Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "ON" at line 1, column 14.
Line 17, column 1

Comment: @MarekRestorationJuris please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue. What you added as a comment is an entirely new issue that should be asked in a new question, not in the comments.

Comment: @MarekRestorationJuris can you edit your question and add that what you posted in here to your question makes it easier to read

Comment: i cannot approve 6min remaining

Comment: @MarekRestorationJuris edited answer to include answer to your second problem